# IAM Role for a Lambda function to be able to isolate ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, network-security-groups

So I wrote a lambda function that it is triggered whenver CloudWatch events receives an ec2 related-finding from GuardDuty, the Lambda function will isolate the EC2 instance ( meaning it'll attach it to an isolated security group ), what are the necessary permissions that the lambda function role should have ? Is this fine for example ?

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
     "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress", 
     "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress", 
     "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress", 
     "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress", 
     "ec2:ModifySecurityGroupRules",
     "ec2:UpdateSecurityGroupRuleDescriptionsIngress", 
     "ec2:UpdateSecurityGroupRuleDescriptionsEgress"
  ],
  "Resource": [
     "arn:aws:ec2:region:111122223333:security-group/*"
  ],
  }
 }
```

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: I kind of don't have the rights to access the environment, I'm an intern in a company, the idea of my project has something to do with this, but I don't have the permissions yet lol, otherwise I would've tried it, I think this role policy is too permissive tho',which is something I wanna avoid.

Comment: If you are an intern, you should tell whoever is supervising you to give you an IAM role with the permissions necessary for you to do your job